# Как в bash-конвейере использовать вывод из python сразу?

Tags: python, bash

Есть python скрипт [script.py](http://script.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from time import sleep
print "Привет!"
sleep 10
```

Тогда если использовать его в bash-конвейере, то вывод происходит не сразу, а после десяти секунд команды sleep.

Пример конвейера:

```
script.py | grep вет
```

Как сделать, чтобы вывод был сразу?

Есть вариант system('echo Привет!'). Но он не работает с русскими буквами. Может его можно использовать?

Comment: удалите sleep 10 :)

Comment: главное условие его оставить

Comment: Ищите аналог fflush() из libc для питона.

Comment: Спасибо! Нашлось легко. Заодно узнал, что такое flush :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Comment: Точно, os.system('echo привет') действительно работает. Может тогда что-то не дописал.

Comment: связанный вопрос (показывает как из Питона запустить программу, чтобы сразу вывод получать как в терминале): [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12419198/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Answer (score 3):

В этом коде вы столкнулись с буферизацией стандартного потока вывода (т.е. информация, переданная на поток вывода передаётся только тогда, когда её объём достаточно большой).

Для того, чтобы в python 2.x оператор `print` (или функция `print` в python 3.x) очистила буфер вывода и передала информацию операционной системе, используется метод `flush` объекта `sys.stdout`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time

print(u"Привет!")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(10)
```

Пример:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 your_script | grep вет
```

Можно не добавлять `flush()` вызовы, а использовать `-u` опцию, которая выключает буферы у стандартных потоков ввода/вывода:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -u your_script.py | grep вет
```

`PYTHONIOENCODING` здесь используется для того, чтобы корректно указать кодировку, в которой осуществляется вывод программы. Она никак не связана с кодировкой исходного кода.

Answer (score 0):

**Кратко**: `$ unbuffer ./script.py | grep pattern`

---

Если вы запустите скрипт, не перенаправляя его вывод в grep, то вывод должен появиться сразу не дожидаясь заполнения буфера:

```
$ ./script.py
Привет!
```

Если стандартный вывод направлен в терминал (предполагается, что человек на него смотрит), то вывод буферизуется построчно (буфер очищается после каждой новой строки).

Если вывод перенаправлен в pipe (потребляется другой программой—grep в данном случае), то буфер не очищается пока он целиком не заполнен (типичный размер 4КБ-8КБ)—возможно по соображениям производительности, чтобы уменьшить кол-во системных вызовов (`write(2)`). Поэтому вывод в примере не показан пока скрипт не завершился (когда все буфера очищаются при нормальном выходе). [Картинка показывающая stdio буферы внутри процессов и pipe буфер в ядре для `command1 | command2` команды](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/):

[image: pipe/stdio buffers]

Это распространённое поведение, среди программ, использующих C stdio, таких как CPython реализация Питона 2. См. вторую причину в [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Существует несколько способов очищать буфер или убрать буферизацию стандартного вывода вообще в Питоне:

- передать `-u` параметр командной строки: `python -u ...`. Можно задать этот параметр в shebang: `#!/usr/bin/python -u` и запускать скрипт напрямую: `./script.py`.
- установить `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` переменную окружения:

  ```
  $ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=nonempty python ...
  ```
- заменить `sys.stdout` на небуферизированный поток (например, с помощью `os.fdopen()`)
- передать `flush=True` параметр в `print()` функцию
- вызвать `sys.stdout.flush()`

См. [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/4279)

В отличии от Питона 2, на Питоне 3, текстовые потоки используют буфер для строк даже если `-u` передан—отличие может проявляться если вывод не содержит новой строки, например:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    sys.stdout.write('before sleep ')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('after sleep')
```

Если передать `-u`, то числа печатаются сразу в обоих версиях (так как `print(i)` печатает новую строку). В Питоне 3, `'before sleep'` задерживается до следующей итерации (когда следующая новая строка печатается), не смотря на `-u` параметр.

Способы, требующие изменения исходного кода (манипуляция `sys.stdout`), могут быть хрупкими (вы можете забыть подставить `flush=True` в нужном месте) или вообще не работать (если вывод в неподконтрольном коде  происходит) и они не всегда нужны. Часто лучше сконфигурировать окружение, в котором запускается скрипт, чтобы включить нужный режим буферизации, вместо редактирования кода.

Если ваш скрипт запускает другие программы, которые могут печатать в стандартный вывод, то можно попробовать подменить C stdio буфер или с помощью [`pty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) заставить программу думать, что она выводит в терминал, а не pipe:

- `$ unbuffer python ...`
- `$ stdbuf -oL -eL python ...`
- `$ script -q -c 'python ...' /dev/null | grep ...`

См. [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/1321).